# Why is the answer GENTLE to the cryptic clue "a tender trap"?

Tags: cryptic-clues

The cryptic clue is a tender trap. The answer is "gentle". I can't see the trap reference. Can somebody help me to see it, please?

Comment: Where did you get the clue from? It seems incomplete to me.

Comment: It would also be useful to know how you know what the answer is. Is it an Actual Official Answer provided by whoever set the original crossword, or is it e.g. your best guess on the basis of other crossing words?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this is from the Northern Echo Prize Crossword from 9 June 2012. (Don't know if that's where OP got the clue from, but it seems to have at least appeared there.) There was a question about this clue on the [Crossword Solver](https://www.crosswordsolver.org/forum/251727/northern-echo-prize-crossword-90612/) forum back then, and one answerer there provided an explanation: "Gentle is a soft maggot used as fishing bait (trap)". I haven't found that meaning in the dictionaries I've looked at, but the meaning seems to be corroborated e.g. on [this](http://www.flyanglersonline.com/features/oldflies/part240.php) angling website.

> Maggots or as they are sometimes called 'gentles,' …

So it's a double definition with tender = gentle and trap = gentle. Not sure what the "a" at the beginning is doing, though. To me it looks like it shouldn't be there.

Comment: The definition of 'gentle' as 'maggot' *is* given in Chambers Dictionary, which would be considered authoritative (at least for UK crosswords).

Comment: It's also in Merriam Webster's Third New International Unabridged.  Maggot ;  especially   : one used as bait or as food for birds or small animals.